# Mac OS X Terminal.app Ubuntu 9.10 SSHD and incorrect keyboard mapping

Tags: macos, ubuntu-9.10, keyboard-layout, xterm, vt100

Does anyone have any Idea how to handle this? I can't stand connecting to certain Ubuntu boxes via Mac OS X because of issues with keyboard layout etc. I have set TERM=vt100 and TERM=xterm-color in Ubuntu .bashrc and also in the Terminal.app advanced preferences and nothing seems to fix this issue. Trying to use arrow keys on slim silver keyboard results in ^[[A etc.

**From Answer**

OS X 10.6.4

When I try to run /lib/terminfo/x/xterm-color I get permission denied? Maybe this is the issue?!

Regular bash login shell. If I sudo often it works. Which leads me to believe the above permissions problem is the cause.

Output from stty -a:

```
$ stty -a
speed 9600 baud; rows 47; columns 181; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = M-^?; eol2 = M-^?; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; flush = ^O;
min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc ixany imaxbel -iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe -echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export TERM=nsterm
```

If that doesn't work, then we need some more information:

1. What is the version of Mac OS X?
2. Is there any differences between the Ubuntu servers? Compare the file `/lib/terminfo/x/xterm-color` from one that is working to one that is not. What about the output of the command `stty -a`
3. In which application does the cursor keys not work? Bash login shell?